# Relative Spritesheet Animation in CSS

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to find the best way to animate a sprite sheet in a webpage using CSS; I found an example at http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/, but the rendering frame is in absolute pixels of 50x72. I need the sizing to be relative so that I can downscale the animated sprite to smaller sizes at smaller screen resolutions; I have tried swapping out the absolute pixel values for relative sizes, and changing the background-position property in the keyframe animation to a relative value, but this does not seem to work (The animation becomes wonky, seemingly slowly moving from one frame to another, instead of playing as it should). Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
   .myAnimationProperties {
        width: 25%;
        height: 25%;
        background-image: url("Images/mySpriteSheet.png");

        -webkit-animation: play .8s steps(6) infinite;
        -moz-animation: play .8s steps(6) infinite;
        -ms-animation: play .8s steps(6) infinite;
        -o-animation: play .8s steps(6) infinite;
        animation: play .8s steps(6) infinite;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes play {
       from { background-position:    0%; }
         to { background-position: -100%; }
    }

    @-moz-keyframes play {
       from { background-position:    0%; }
         to { background-position: -100%; }
    }

    @-ms-keyframes play {
       from { background-position:    0%; }
         to { background-position: -100%; }
    }

    @-o-keyframes play {
       from { background-position:    0%; }
         to { background-position: -100%; }
    }

    @keyframes play {
       from { background-position:    0%; }
         to { background-position: -100%; }
    }
```

Comment: Do you really need to sizing to be relative?  Could you not use media queries to use a range of different absolute sizes based on screen size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you change the `background-size` for smaller screens?

Comment: I tried adding that, but I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly or if it doesn't work. I obtained the width and height of the spritesheet itself relative to its native resolution, and set the background-size property to those two values; however, this resulted in what appeared to be numerous tiny complete spritesheets within the 25%,25% rendering frame.

On a side note, is background-size supported by all browsers? If I remember correctly, I read somewhere that some recent versions of IE do not support it.

Comment: Also, maybe `transform: scale(n)` could help you.

Comment: As for background-size, all browsers that support CSS animations also support background-size: http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size